# cached memory and free command

Tags: memory, memcached, free

I have a 2 cpu server running SLES 11.4 x86-64 and it has 1.5 tb of RAM.

```
>free -g

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1514        284       1230        268          0        269
```

Running a number crunching software, which has worked fine in the past, giving us problems lately running slow and crashing, trying to figure out why.

I tried to do a `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and that did not work.  It usually puts `cached` to zero, did not work this time.

my questions are:

- what would cause `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` not to work?
- does the *cached* value even matter?
- is there another way to accurately find out current state of RAM used/cached/whatever besides the *free* command?
- given this type of problem and troubleshooting, any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

for the crashing part check `dmesg`, for the slowness try `vmstat 2` and keep it running when you execute the crunshing app, it should shed some light on what the bottleneck might be.